# Can someone explain what's going on with this code? What's <> after function name?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't understand the following piece of code. 
What is

```
export default function forwardRef<Props, ElementType: React$ElementType>(
      render: (props: Props, ref: React$Ref<ElementType>) => React$Node,
    )
```

trying to do? This file can be found in react repo under forwardRef.js

Comment: Looks like TypeScript

Comment: it's from react.js

Comment: Then it's probably Flow Type, https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/

Comment: as they say it could be typscript or flow inferring a type